# Cannot install synaptic on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dependencies, synaptic

I cannot install synaptic on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS PC. Getting the following error. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Go to the terminal and run `sudo apt update` (type your password) then `sudo apt upgrade`.  Then try installing Synaptic again.

Comment: If the above recommendation produces errors make sure to edit your question and post the full error messages.

Answer (score 3):

Run the following commands in your terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt -f install
sudo apt install synaptic
```

When prompted, enter your password.  This should install synaptic for you, along with clearing up broken packages (fixing dependency issues) and updating your system.

<sub>Special thanks to @DKBose for pointing out sudo apt clean.  :)</sub>

Comment: @DKBose, excellent thoughts, thanks for pointing out.  :)

Comment: @DKBose, it's still there: I'm guessing it's an oversight in the documentation.